# new File() gives me undefined File in javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to open a local file and create a **`File`** object from an image file using the following code

```
var newFileObj = new File([buffer],fileObj.originalname,{type: fileObj.mimetype});
```

However this gives me File is undefined. I am using **nodejs v7.0.0**

**Do i need to require any file before for using File type?**

**P.S- This is a REST API , there is no html involved.**

Comment: The `File` API isn't implemented for Node.js, instead you'd use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: I am uploading the file to a cloudinary bucket which accepts **File** Object. Can I use fs to create such File Object? @robertklep

Comment: The [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) interface is part of the Web API, and is not defined in ECMAScript. How are you *using* the File instance you're trying to create?

Comment: I am trying to post to to cloudinary url with this File Object as a field.  `let upload = request.post(CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL)
                                                .field('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET)
                                                .field('file', newFileObj);` @idbehold

Comment: @GouravSaha take a look at this: https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads (it uses `fs.createReadStream` to open, read and upload files)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'fs' for read/write file in node world. Here is the link

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

```
fs.open('myfile', 'r', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      console.error('myfile does not exist');
      return;
    }

    throw err;
  }

  readMyData(fd);
});
```